# Does chrome extension auto-update skips to last version or do incremental version update until the lastest one?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I manage a chrome extension and I have a bug in one version that is triggered when it updates to the "buggish" version. Let's say versions 1.0.0 works, 1.0.1 is buggish and 1.0.2 work. The 1.0.2 is live on the chrome store.

So the buggish behavior happen when user go from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 for sure. But as "now" the 1.0.2 is live on the store, does a user having locally the 1.0.0 version gets the 1.0.2 when chrome auto-update the extension or does it update 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 successively ?

Comment: Fast answer: "**it skips to last version**"
The runtime.onInstalled event handler lets you know which version you are upgrading from via the "previousVersion" property. It's up to you to write a few lines of code (in that handler) to manage every possible combination.

For example, a user may have a very old version installed on their browser and that browser may have been closed for a long time.

Comment: Loud and clear many thanks :)

Comment: The last version is also the only one possible. Chrome web store does not store old versions.
Firefox Addon Store, on the other hand, stores all versions of an extension and allows the developer to delete older versions (or even intermediate versions).
The historicization applied by FF is ONLY useful to allow outdated versions of the browser to download the latest version compatible with that browser (it is not necessarily the latest).
If there are several compatible versions, skip all the "lower" ones and go directly to the "higher" one.